# No Response in Speech Recognition Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, speech-recognition

I have installed speech recognition module along with pyaudio on my Python 2.7 in windows. When I execute the python script it executes with no error but the program remains still to listen from the user but does not give any response, i.e., the program does not "listen".
Hope you guys can help me out here! (A newbie!)

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:                # use the default microphone as the audio source
    audio = r.listen(source)                   # listen for the first phrase and extract it into audio data

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
except LookupError:                            # speech is unintelligible
    print("Could not understand audio")
```

Comment: The code : https://pastebin.com/GVWPEypV

Comment: What does the program output? Does it change if you change the fourth line to `audio = r.listen(source, timeout=10)`?

Comment: It just waits for input...

Comment: I tried changing the fourth line as suggested and after waiting for like 10 sec this error was displayed : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/speechrecognization/speech.py", line 4, in <module>
    audio = r.listen(source, timeout=10)                   # listen for the first phrase and extract it into audio data
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 544, in listen
    raise WaitTimeoutError("listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start")
speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError: listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start

Comment: What word or phrase are you saying? Are you sure your microphone settings are correct (volume etc.)? Do you even *have* a microphone? To test, try recording to a file and playing it back, and/or [listening to a file](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/audio_transcribe.py#L13).

Comment: I figured it. Installed pywin32 and it works now! Thanks!